# To open the file (from a file path) that resides in another file powershell

Tags: powershell

I have file called 'main_file.txt' (c:temp\main_file.txt) that contains a single line of file path of another file like below.

```
\\mynewfolder\folder\sub_file.csv
```

Here in the below code, I need to access the above sub_file.csv (\mynewfolder\folder\sub_file.csv)and use the contents to do some process. How to **change my below first line of code** to access the contents of the **sub_file.csv which is available as a path inside the main_file.txt**.

```
$txt = Get-Content "how to get the contents of sub_file.csv" | Out-String
{
...do some process with the contents of sub_file.csv..
...
...
}
```

Could you please help.

Comment: `$txt = c:\temp\main_file.txt | % { "Do stuff" }` ?

Comment: Something like this? `a = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\main_file.txt`
`Import-Csv -Path $a` What are you trying to do with the CSV file?

Comment: I'm wondering why you're doing this though, you might aswell just put the path of the csv file in the `import-csv` cmd-let straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this:

```
$handle = Get-Content c:\temp\main_file.txt
$content = Import-Csv $handle
$content | Format-Table
```

The variable $content should contain an array of PSObjects where each object represents a record from the csv file.  I've included the last command as just a sample of doing something with the contents after reading them.

If your csv data is very big, you may not want to read it all into a variable before you process it.  Instead, you may want to feed the output of Import-Csv into a pipeline, and process the records one at a time.